In a spreadsheet how do I keep a relative reference at a fixed offset to the current cell, fo example the cell three cells above the current one
I've seen a similar question regarding absolute references, How to keep a spreadsheet cell reference fixed when rows are inserted? and I think the solution may be similar.
I'm using a spreadsheet to do impedance calculations, and I want to be able to move, copy and paste blocks of formulae without breaking them. Each block takes its input from the four cells immediately above it. This MOSTLY works but breaks if I want to add or remove lines from the spreadsheet.
I'm looking for a way to say I want the cell N cells above the current one, and if I delete that line it will still reference the cell that is N cells above.
With a relative reference if the cell being referenced is deleted it becomes an invalid reference.

A formula which always refers to the cell three rows above the cell containing the formula (assuming the formula itself is in A8):
=INDIRECT("R"&ROW(A8)-3&"C"&COLUMN(A8),FALSE)

You can copy the formula around, delete the target row, and it will still refer to whatever is three rows above it.

In excel, you can write a cell notation as follows: =A1.
This refers to Cell A1, and if you copy the cell this formula is in and paste it in the cell below, A1 is automatically changed to A2 as it the cell relative to your current cell.
The same applies for if you paste it in the cell to the right, you get =B1.
Because it is not always wanted to actually change the cell, Excell has the option to always keep a row and/or column the same, regardless of if you move it or not.
You can do this by prepending a $ sign to the letter or number.
If you want A1 to always keep the A, but have the 1 be relative, the A needs to change to $A. If you always want to keep the 1, but have the A be relative, the 1 needs to change to $1. If you want both to stay the same they both have to change: so $A$1.
The 4 options can be: =A1, =$A1, =A$1 or =$A$1.
Of course, when you delete a row, all cells are recalculated, and the relative numbers are automatically updated to change (excel will try to keep pointing them at the right cell. So if you don't want these cells to update and you basically want that if the cell is moved a different cell is referenced, you add the $.

Excel also allows cells to be addressed in "RC notation" or "Multiplan notation", where both rows and columns are numbered, and a particular cell is e.g. R1C5 (instead of A5). You can make a cell reference entirely relative in this notation by enclosing the (signed) offset in square brackets - for example, the cell one up and three left is R[-1]C[-3].

While entirely true what @JeffZeitlin says, it is essentially the same thing, just written differently. If you switch to RC notation and back, Excel will add the $'s if you use R1C5 instead of R[-1]C[-3]. It really depends on what you prefer.
